# Can't scroll to top of flex item that is overflowing container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In attempting to make a useful modal using flexbox, I found what seems to be a browser issue and am wondering if there is a known fix or workaround -- or ideas on how to resolve it.

The thing I'm trying to solve has two aspects. First, getting the modal window vertically centered, which works as expected. The second is to get the modal window to scroll -- externally, so the whole modal window scrolls, not the contents within it (this is so you can have dropdowns and other UI elements that can extend outside of the bounds of the modal -- like a custom date picker, etc.)

However, when combining the vertical centering with scroll bars, the top of the modal can become inaccessible as it begins to overflow. In the above example, you can resize to force the overflow, and in doing so it allows you to scroll to the bottom of the modal, but not to the top (first paragraph is cut off).

```css
.modal-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.modal-container .modal-window {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* Optional support to confirm scroll behavior makes sense in IE10
  //-ms-flex-direction: column;
  //-ms-flex-align: center;
  //-ms-flex-pack: center; */
  height: 100%;
}
.modal-container .modal-window .modal-content {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-container">
    <div class="modal-window">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <p class="p3">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            <p class="p3">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            <p class="p3">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This affects (current) Firefox, Safari, Chrome, and Opera. It does interestingly behave correctly in IE10 if you comment in the IE10 vendor prefixed CSS -- I did not bother testing in IE11 yet, but assume the behavior matches that of IE10.

Here's the link to the example code (highly simplified)

https://jsfiddle.net/dh9k18k0/2/

Answer (score 903, accepted):

### The Problem

Flexbox makes centering very easy.

By simply applying `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center` to the flex container, your flex item(s) will be vertically and horizontally centered.

However, there is a problem with this method when the flex item is bigger than the flex container.

As noted in the question, when the flex item overflows the container the top becomes inaccessible.

[image]

For horizontal overflow, the left section becomes inaccessible (or right section, in RTL languages).

Here's an example with an LTR container having `justify-content: center` and three flex items:

[image]

*See the bottom of this answer for an explanation of this behavior.*

---

### Solution #1

To fix this problem use [**flexbox auto margins**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276), instead of `justify-content`.

With `auto` margins, an overflowing flex item can be vertically and horizontally centered without losing access to any part of it.

So instead of this code on the flex container:

```css
#flex-container {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Use this code on the flex item:

```css
.flex-item {
    margin: auto;
}
```

[image]

[**Revised Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/dh9k18k0/9/)

---

### Solution #2 (not yet implemented in most browsers)

Add the `safe` value to your keyword alignment rule, like this:

```css
justify-content: safe center
```

or

```css
align-self: safe center
```

From the [CSS Box Alignment Module specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/):

> [**4.4. Overflow Alignment: the `safe` and `unsafe` keywords and
> scroll safety
> limits**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#overflow-values)
>
> When the [flex item] is larger than the [flex container], it will
> overflow. Some alignment modes, if honored in this situation, may
> cause data loss: for example, if the contents of a sidebar are
> centered, when they overflow they may send part of their boxes past
> the viewport’s start edge, which can’t be scrolled to.
>
> To control this situation, an ***overflow alignment*** mode can be
> explicitly specified. `Unsafe` alignment honors the specified
> alignment mode in overflow situations, even if it causes data loss,
> while `safe` alignment changes the alignment mode in overflow
> situations in an attempt to avoid data loss.
>
> The default behavior is to contain the alignment subject within the
> scrollable area, though at the time of writing this safety feature is
> not yet implemented.
>
> ***`safe`***
>
> If the size of the [flex item] overflows the [flex container], the
> [flex item] is instead aligned as if the alignment mode were
> [`flex-start`].
>
> ***`unsafe`***
>
> Regardless of the relative sizes of the [flex item] and [flex
> container], the given alignment value is honored.

*Note: The Box Alignment Module is for use across multiple box layout models, not just flex. So in the spec excerpt above, the terms in brackets actually say "alignment subject", "alignment container" and "`start`".  I used flex-specific terms to keep the focus on this particular problem.*

---

### Explanation for scroll limitation from MDN:

> [**Flex item
> considerations**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes#Flex_item_considerations)
>
> Flexbox's alignment properties do "true" centering, unlike other
> centering methods in CSS. This means that the flex items will stay
> centered, even if they overflow the flex container.
>
> This can sometimes be problematic, however, if they overflow past the
> top edge of the page, or the left edge [...], as
> you can't scroll to that area, even if there is content there!
>
> In a future release, the alignment properties will be extended to have
> a "safe" option as well.
>
> For now, if this is a concern, you can instead use margins to achieve
> centering, as they'll respond in a "safe" way and stop centering if
> they overflow.
>
> Instead of using the `align-` properties, just put `auto` margins on
> the flex items you wish to center.
>
> Instead of the `justify-` properties, put auto margins on the outside
> edges of the first and last flex items in the flex container.
>
> The `auto` margins will "flex" and assume the leftover space,
> centering the flex items when there is leftover space, and switching
> to normal alignment when not.
>
> However, if you're trying to replace `justify-content` with
> margin-based centering in a multi-line flexbox, you're probably out of
> luck, as you need to put the margins on the first and last flex item
> on each line. Unless you can predict ahead of time which items will
> end up on which line, you can't reliably use margin-based centering in
> the main axis to replace the `justify-content` property.

Comment: I've worked up a simple example that worked for me [on CodePen](http://codepen.io/trey/pen/GqjYym).

Comment: It should be noted that is does not work in IE11. The background will be cut off.

Comment: @Daniel, I just tested the code in IE11. Nothing is inaccessible. In fact, the problem described in the question doesn't even exist in IE11. You may be referring to the text overflow happening only in IE11. That's another issue for another question.

Comment: To fix issue in IE11: add `align-items: flex-start` to the flex container and keep `margin: auto` for flex item.

Comment: If anyone else on IE11 is struggling with the height of the container not extending to the full height of the content. Adding a `flex: 0 0 auto` to the flex item fixed it for me.

Comment: this doesn't work for images. I have tried placing <img> in place of div with class="modal-content", but it doesn't work. It cuts my image from the top. Can anyone help?

Comment: This does not work for me when using flex-direction: column;

Comment: @Stefan - Does the "Revised Demo" fiddle work for you? It uses `flex-direction: column`. Simplify your situation until you find what you have done differently. You might need to: 1) *remove* all `justify-content: center;` lines on those elements!! 2) *add* `display: flex; flex-direction: column` on *all* levels of your hierarchy (except the *innermost one*). 3) *add* `flex: 1;` on *all* levels of hierarchy (except *outermost* one). Use different background colors, and examine/modify CSS with Chrome "Inspect". One mistake I made was not changing a `.name` to `#name` where I used an `id`.

Comment: `safe center`  is great. Only supported in Firefox so far however: https://caniuse.com/#search=flex%20safe

Comment: If you want to have specified margins between elements (e.g., a card carousel), you can set `margin: auto` for only the first and the last item.

Comment: To fix this only for vertical, use `margin: auto 0;`

Comment: it's funny that it needs safe. why isn't it the default behavior.... content should at all cost always be available in the view.. That looks like a "use that keyword to fix it" feature.

Answer (score 37):

I managed to pull this off with just 3 containers. The trick is to separate the flexbox container from the container that controls the scrolling. Lastly, put everything into a root container to center it all. Here are the essential styles to create the effect:

```css
.root {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.scroll-container {
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="scroll-container">
    <div class="flex-container">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've created a demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/r5jxtgba/14/

Comment: remember, dont give `flex: 1 1 auto` to the `scroll-container`. I was doing this with on habit and got into problem.

Comment: The jsfiddle shows that it doesn't work when you add more content inside the container.

Comment: You're right. Apparently this solution only works if the initial content is smaller than its container before the screen is resized.

Comment: If you remove the fixed height from flex-container then this will work in the demo example, a fixed height to the flex-container wouldn't allow it to take the entire height that all the cumulative flex-children take and thus defeats the purpose of having a scroll-container.

Answer (score 28):

I played around with min-height a bit before posting, but was not aware of the intrinsic sizing constraints that are fairly new to the spec.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width

Adding a `min-height: min-content` to the flexbox area does resolve the issue in Chrome, and with vendor prefixes also fixes Opera and Safari, though Firefox remains unresolved.

```
min-height: -moz-min-content; // not implemented
min-height: -webkit-min-content // works for opera and safari
min-height: min-content // works for chrome
```

Still looking for ideas on Firefox, and other potential solutions.

Comment: I just wanted to say that it already works for me in Firefox. So the solution with min-content was perfect.

Comment: @pudgereyem I guess they implemented it then. The other solution with `margin: auto` stops `flex-basis` from working for me whereas this answer solved both issues.

Comment: @jejacks0n not working if you add it to flex parent

Answer (score 4):

I think I found a solution. It works with [lots of text](https://jsbin.com/feqopom/3/edit?html,css,output) and [a little text](https://jsbin.com/feqopom/4/edit?html,css,output). You don't need to specify the widths of anything, and it *should* work in IE8.

```css
.wrap1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.wrap2 {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrap3 {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
.wrap4 {
  margin: 10px;
}
.dialog {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap1">
  <div class="wrap2">
    <div class="wrap3">
      <div class="wrap4">
        <div class="dialog">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this!

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="item">First item</div>
    <div class="item">Second item</div>
    <div class="item">Third item</div>
</div>
```

```scss
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;

    .item:first-child {
        margin-left: auto;
    }

    .item:last-child {
        margin-right: auto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use the `margin: auto` technique, but if you would like to not use flexbox for whatever reason, you can use the pseudo element with vertical align hack to accomplish this.

[Example](https://codepen.io/dslavov/pen/eYReEeN)

If codepen does not work

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="modal"></div>
</div>

<style>
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  overflow-y: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Required for centering */
.wrapper:before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

.modal {
  /* Required for centering */
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;


  text-align: left;
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
</style>
```

It works by creating an inline element, which as the full height of the parent and is displayed as inline-block, just as your target element ( .modal ), then `vertical-align: middle` is used on both, and the browser does its magic - it aligns the .modal and the pseudo element as though they were regular text. You can also use top/bottom vertical align on the modal div. Combined with text-align, the modal can be placed in any position.

You can use `text-align: center` on the parent to center the dialog horizontally. Should be supported in any browser and the overflow also works.

At the time of writing ( 9/15/2021 ), going to Google in incognito mode shows a cookie policy modal, which uses this technique for centering.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `display: grid` instead.

Comment: This has the same effect!

Comment: You should copy the snippet down and demonstrate your solution.

Answer (score 1):

My case uses horizontal flex and overflow, and is indeed a boomer. I'm trying to make scrollable content on horizontal flex, like example below:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

pre {
  padding: 30px;
  background: gray;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <pre>Item</pre>
  <pre>Item</pre>
  <pre>Item</pre>
  <pre>Item</pre>
  <pre>Item</pre>
  <pre>Item</pre>
</div>
```

The solution was by using `margin:auto` on the first and last element instead:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

pre {
  padding: 30px;
  background: gray;
  margin: 20px;
}

pre:first-child { margin-left: auto; }

pre:last-child { margin-right: auto; }
```

```html
<p>When overflow:</p>
<div>
  <pre>Item</pre>
  <pre>Item</pre>
  <pre>Item</pre>
  <pre>Item</pre>
  <pre>Item</pre>
  <pre>Item</pre>
  <pre>Item</pre>
</div>


<p>When not overflow:</p>
<div>
  <pre>Item</pre>
  <pre>Item</pre>
  <pre>Item</pre>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN, the `safe` value can now be provided to properties like [`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) and [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content). It's described as follows:

> If the size of the item overflows the alignment container, the item is instead aligned as if the alignment mode were `start`.

So, it might be used as follows.

```
.rule
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: safe center;
}
```

However, it's unclear how much browser support it has, I could not find any examples of its use, and I have been having some issues with it myself. Mentioning it here to draw more attention to it.

Comment: According to the (current) MDN pages, "safe" and "unsafe" are still Firefox-only at this point (well, Safari and most mobile browsers have unknown support -- I'd play it safe and assume no support).

Comment: MDN reports Firefox support, but when I tested it in Firefox, it didn't seem to work. https://jsbin.com/pimoqof/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

I also managed to do it using extra container

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal-container">
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="content-container">
       <div class="content">
         <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.modal-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.modal {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #aaa;
  height: 80%;
  width: 90%;
}

.content-container {
  background-color: blue;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding:0;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 900px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

in jsfiddle > https://jsfiddle.net/Nash171/cpf4weq5/

change *.content* width/height values and see

Answer (score 0):

2 Container Flex Method with Table fallback tested IE8-9, flex works in IE10,11.
Edit: Edited to ensure vertical centering when minimal content, added legacy support.

The issue stems from height being inherited from the viewport size which causes children to overflow, as Michael answered. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33455342/3500688

something more simple and use flex to maintain the layout within the popup container(content):

```css
#popup {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
min-height: 100vh;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
margin: auto;
overflow: auto;
height: 100%;
bottom: 0;
display: flex;
align-items: flex-start;
box-sizing:border-box;
padding:2em 20px;
}
.container {
background-color: #fff;
margin: auto;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;
background: #fff;
/* width: 100%; */
max-width: 500px;
padding: 10px;
    /* display: flex; */
    /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
}
  <!--[if lt IE 10]>
<style>
   #popup {
   display: table;
   width:100%;
  }
  .iewrapper {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
  }
 </style>
 <![endif]-->
```

```html
<div id="popup">
 <!--[if lt IE 10]>
<div class="iewrapper">
<![endif]-->
    <div class="container">
        <p class="p3">Test</p>
    <p class="p3">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <p class="p3">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
 <!--[if lt IE 10]>
<div class="iewrapper">
<![endif]-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to center row of items vertically and horizontally which also had `flex-wrap` enabled. I managed to make it work with this solution, which only needs 2 containers:

```html
<div class="outside-container">
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="flex-items">
        <div class="item">Item 1</div>
        <div class="item">Item 2</div>
        <div class="item">Item 3</div>
        <div class="item">Item 4</div>
        <div class="item">Item 5</div>
        <div class="item">Item 6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```css
.outside-container {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
}
.flex-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.flex-items {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: auto;
  gap: 1rem;
  row-gap: 1rem;
}
.item {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

The important parts are the `flex-container` and `flex-items` classes. The `outside-container` mimics the div which holds this component and the `item` class just makes it easier to test the overflow scrolling.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `justify-content: center`, add two `div` with `flex: 1` as the first and the last child of your flex container.

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden auto;
}

.flex-1 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="flex-1"></div>
      <h1>
        This is a static template, there is no bundler or bundling involved!
      </h1>
      <p>
        This is a static template, there is no bundler or bundling involved!
        This is a static template, there is no bundler or bundling involved!
      </p>
      <div class="flex-1"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```