# Top gets cut off when using Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using flexbox to layout `div's`. When I have a lot of `li's` inside the `div`, (with each `li` having a width of 100%/3) the top gets cut off. So I searched online, and they said to insert `margin: auto` to the inner `div`. When I do that, I get a new problem. Let me show you:

With `margin: auto` **not** applied:

```css
body, html {
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
#outerWrapper {
    background-color: aqua;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start; /* This is ignored */
    align-items: center;
    overflow: auto;
    
}

#innerWrapper {
   /* margin:auto; /* If this line is removed, then it does flex-start, but the top is cut off */
    width: 70%;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    align-content:flex-start;
}


li {
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex-basis:calc(100%/3);
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerWrapper">
    <ul id="innerWrapper">
        <li class="flex-item">1</li>
        <li class="flex-item">2</li>
        <li class="flex-item">3</li>
        <li class="flex-item">4</li>
        <li class="flex-item">5</li>
        <li class="flex-item">6</li>
        <li class="flex-item">7</li>
        <li class="flex-item">8</li>
        <li class="flex-item">9</li>
        <li class="flex-item">10</li>
        <li class="flex-item">11</li>
        <li class="flex-item">12</li>
        <li class="flex-item">13</li>
        <li class="flex-item">14</li>
        <li class="flex-item">15</li>
        <li class="flex-item">16</li>
        <li class="flex-item">17</li>
        <li class="flex-item">18</li>
        <li class="flex-item">19</li>
        <li class="flex-item">20</li>
        <li class="flex-item">21</li>
        <li class="flex-item">22</li>
        <li class="flex-item">23</li>
        <li class="flex-item">24</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### JSFiddle

**Problem:** `flex-start` works, but the top is cut off.

---

With `margin: auto` applied:

```css
body, html {
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
#outerWrapper {
    background-color: aqua;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start; /* This is ignored */
    align-items: center;
    overflow: auto;
    
}

#innerWrapper {
   margin:auto; /* If this line is removed, then it does flex-start, but the top is cut off */
    width: 70%;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    align-content:flex-start;
}


li {
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex-basis:calc(100%/3);
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerWrapper">
    <ul id="innerWrapper">
        <li class="flex-item">1</li>
        <li class="flex-item">2</li>
        <li class="flex-item">3</li>
        <li class="flex-item">4</li>
        <li class="flex-item">5</li>
        <li class="flex-item">6</li>
        <li class="flex-item">7</li>
        <li class="flex-item">8</li>
        <li class="flex-item">9</li>
        <li class="flex-item">10</li>
        <li class="flex-item">11</li>
        <li class="flex-item">12</li>
        <li class="flex-item">13</li>
        <li class="flex-item">14</li>
        <li class="flex-item">15</li>
        <li class="flex-item">16</li>
        <li class="flex-item">17</li>
        <li class="flex-item">18</li>
        <li class="flex-item">19</li>
        <li class="flex-item">20</li>
        <li class="flex-item">21</li>
        <li class="flex-item">22</li>
        <li class="flex-item">23</li>
        <li class="flex-item">24</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### JSFiddle

**Problem:** `flex-start` doesn't work, but top is not cut off.

My question is, how can I have `justify-content: flex-start` and have the top not get cut off?

Comment: Here's an explanation for the scroll limitation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33455342/3597276

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Auto margins push the flex item. If you use `margin: auto`, the element will be pushed equally from all sides, so it will be centered.

If you want it to be aligned to the top, only set the `margin-bottom: auto`, and let `margin-top` be `0`.

```css
#innerWrapper {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#outerWrapper {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  /* This is ignored */
  align-items: center;
  overflow: auto;
}
#innerWrapper {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  width: 70%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-basis: calc(100%/3);
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerWrapper">
  <ul id="innerWrapper">
    <li class="flex-item">1</li>
    <li class="flex-item">2</li>
    <li class="flex-item">3</li>
    <li class="flex-item">4</li>
    <li class="flex-item">5</li>
    <li class="flex-item">6</li>
    <li class="flex-item">7</li>
    <li class="flex-item">8</li>
    <li class="flex-item">9</li>
    <li class="flex-item">10</li>
    <li class="flex-item">11</li>
    <li class="flex-item">12</li>
    <li class="flex-item">13</li>
    <li class="flex-item">14</li>
    <li class="flex-item">15</li>
    <li class="flex-item">16</li>
    <li class="flex-item">17</li>
    <li class="flex-item">18</li>
    <li class="flex-item">19</li>
    <li class="flex-item">20</li>
    <li class="flex-item">21</li>
    <li class="flex-item">22</li>
    <li class="flex-item">23</li>
    <li class="flex-item">24</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Alternatively, forgot about auto margins and remove the code which produces the cut:

```css
#outerWrapper {
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#outerWrapper {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  overflow: auto;
}
#innerWrapper {
  margin: 0;
  width: 70%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-basis: calc(100%/3);
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerWrapper">
  <ul id="innerWrapper">
    <li class="flex-item">1</li>
    <li class="flex-item">2</li>
    <li class="flex-item">3</li>
    <li class="flex-item">4</li>
    <li class="flex-item">5</li>
    <li class="flex-item">6</li>
    <li class="flex-item">7</li>
    <li class="flex-item">8</li>
    <li class="flex-item">9</li>
    <li class="flex-item">10</li>
    <li class="flex-item">11</li>
    <li class="flex-item">12</li>
    <li class="flex-item">13</li>
    <li class="flex-item">14</li>
    <li class="flex-item">15</li>
    <li class="flex-item">16</li>
    <li class="flex-item">17</li>
    <li class="flex-item">18</li>
    <li class="flex-item">19</li>
    <li class="flex-item">20</li>
    <li class="flex-item">21</li>
    <li class="flex-item">22</li>
    <li class="flex-item">23</li>
    <li class="flex-item">24</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Now if I don't have as many `li's`, `align-items: center` doesn't work. Lemme show you: http://jsfiddle.net/e0ctrmut/1/

Comment: @Jessica I thought you wanted to align the items to the top?

Comment: I want to have both options. (You're right, I didn't say that in my question.)

Comment: @Jessica Then I suggest switching between `#innerWrapper {margin-bottom:auto}` and `#innerWrapper {margin-top:auto;margin-bottom:auto}`.

Comment: `margin-top:auto;margin-bottom:auto` causes weird results

Comment: @Jessica Which weird results?

Comment: Oh, never mind! I didn't add a semi-colon at the end of it. (Wasted so much time for just 1 semi colon!) Lemme do some testing, and see if I have it. You're saying I have to use JavaScript, right?

Comment: *Auto margins push the flex item. If you use `margin: auto`, the element will be pushed equally from all sides, so it will be centered.* This works when the content overflows on the top. It doesn't seem to have an effect when content overflows on the left. To solve a horizontal scroll limitation, I've only come up with a series of hacks. Any ideas? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33590889/when-centering-horizontally-lis-get-cut-off

Comment: @Michael_B That case is problematic because a multicolumn flexbox with `width: auto` doesn't increase its width to cover all columns, only the first one. Then I don't know how to center it properly.

Answer (score 11):

use

```
.flex-parent{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


.flex-child{
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem and an internet search brought me here.

The answer above didn't work in my case, but what did work was wrapping my content container (that was getting cut off) in a `div` styled with a `min-height:0;` rule.

Note: I used `min-height` because I am using a columnar layout - it would be `min-width` for rows. In most cases using both probably wouldn't hurt.

**html:**

```
<div class="flex-fix">

    <div>This content was getting cut off...</div>

</div>
```

**css:**

```
.flex-fix {

    min-height: 0;
    min-width:  0;

}
```

*I got the clue from this article on css-tricks.com:* [Flexbox and Truncated Text](https://css-tricks.com/flexbox-truncated-text/)

Hope this helps.