# When centering horizontally, li's get cut off

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to layout `li's` using `flexbox`. I have them set to column, with 3 `li's` in each column. The problem is when I want the `ul` centered.

I am centering the `ul` using `align-content: center`. When I do that, and have more `li's` than the page can show (overflowed), the `li's` at the beginning get cut off. (The ones on the left side get cut off, but the ones on the right side display fine.)

**I will not have a specific number of `li's`, it could range from 4 to 50.** So I therefore cannot remove `align-content: center`, because when I have a small amount of `li's`, (let's say 4), the results are not what I want.

How can I center the `ul` without having it get cut off?

#### JSFiddle

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
div {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color:aqua;
}
ul {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: center;
}
li {
    flex-basis: calc(100% / 3 - 2px);
    /* Subtract the border */
    color: firebrick;
    border: 1px solid firebrick;
    background-color: greenYellow;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
        <li>10</li>
        <li>11</li>
        <li>12</li>
        <li>13</li>
        <li>14</li>
        <li>15</li>
        <li>16</li>
        <li>17</li>
        <li>18</li>
        <li>19</li>
        <li>20</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: jessica, your problem is really cumbersome. But try to use align-content:flex-start;

Comment: That works, but then when there are only 4 `li's` the `ul` isn't centered

Comment: ok so you want, if there are less contents, content must be aligned center and when content increases, it must be aligned to left?

Comment: I want it to always be centered. The problem is, when there are a lot of `li's` the content on the left gets cut off

Comment: I want the `ul` to be centered. When I use `display:inline-block` for the `ui`, I don't get `flexbox's` layout, which I need.

Comment: ok i got your problem. Remove the align-content style and add margin-left:20%; and margin-right:auto; in your style

Comment: This case is problematic because a multicolumn flexbox with `width: auto` doesn't increase its width to cover all columns, only the first one. Then I don't know how to center it properly. I would use JS to count the items and wrap each row in an element, and use `flex-direction: row`.

Comment: So you're saying I should have a `ul` for every row?

Comment: I am working on this at the moment, but one mistake I found already is that `display: flex` only works **one** level deep, so your **LI**'s are plain child elements of your **UL**, setting flexbox attributes on these **LI**'s have no effect. I missed that one often in the beginning. SO, make your UL `display: flex` and the **DIV** just a generic wrapper.

Comment: **update** I missed the UL inline-flex, sorry about that...

Comment: @Jessica - This doesn't solve your problem, but if you use [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) then you don't need to use calc with the `flex-basis` to compensate for the border. You can just use 50% and the border (and any padding) is calculated into the width and height: [here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/m8bykfkr/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I center the ul without having it get cut off?

That was a really good question, had some trouble figuring a way to achieve this behavior.

I don't believe you will find a pure `CSS` solution, however we can do it using a bit of `javascript`.

Basically i´ve created a script attached to the window resize event that will do the following:

1. check how many items we have inside our wrapper element: `#wrapper`
2. divide the number of elements by 3 (since we have 3 elements in each column) to discover how many columns will be needed to display the items
3. assign a width to the wrapper element using the following formula: number of columns * width of each item (in our case that's `200px`)

Doing that we force the overflow in the parent element, and the scrollbar will have a normal behavior, showing every element.

The full code is available in [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/gLj9te6k/).

Check the following example:

```js
function onResize() {

  var wrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper');

  var items = wrapper.querySelectorAll('li');

  var columns = Math.ceil(items.length / 3);

  var width = 200 * columns;

  wrapper.style.width = width > window.innerWidth ? width + 'px' : '100%';

}

onResize();

window.addEventListener('resize', onResize);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: aqua;
}
ul {
  height: 75%;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
li {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 3 - 2px);
  color: firebrick;
  border: 1px solid firebrick;
  background-color: greenYellow;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please add a JSFiddle?

Comment: @Jessica there you go

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm still trying to understand it. Just curious, is it important (or why did you) round it up (`Math.ceil`)?

Comment: @Jessica lets imagine you have 10 items. if i wasn't rounding up the number of columns would be 3 instead of 4, and the width calculations would be wrong and the wrapper would be smaller than needed by 1 item.

Comment: In JSLint, I'm getting the following error: `Missing radix parameter. var column...`

Comment: @Jessica check [Missing radix parameter](https://jslinterrors.com/missing-radix-parameter). you can fix that by setting the radix in the `parseInt` call. In fact we can simple remove it since we are getting a number from the Math.ceil.

Comment: Good point! Also, I'm trying to do this in JQuery, When I try doing: `var wrapper = $('#wrapper')` it doesn't work. Do you know why?

Comment: Can't even guess until you post the error / screenshot. Should have worked. Maybe you are calling it before the element exists?

Comment: @Jessica there you go, fixed for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dsf9a0co/1/). The jquery selector was working fine, however you were using the querySelectorAll in the jquery object, and that is not a jquery function. If you are going to use jquery change all the selectors.

Comment: In the last JSFiddle you created, I think you may have forgotten "`width >`" Here's an updated version of the [JSFiddle with the fix](http://jsfiddle.net/dsf9a0co/4/).

Comment: While Romulo's answer solves your immediate problem, it is not waterproof. Add `ul:before` and `ul:after` with some content to your CSS and you will see that the calculations fail. IMHO I think you should reopen the question as the problem lies in the fact that your code was correct al along, but you stumbled over a FLEXBOX bug regarding your `ul {align-content: center;}`. One would expect the scrollbar to be twice as wide in this case and the scroll-thumb centered inside the (overflowing) parent. Neither FF, CH nor IE show this result. IE however does not cut the leftsided blocks. PLS reopen.

Comment: ....... the question as I think this problem needs more diving into and a waterproof solution properly working around the problem you presented. Tested in FF DE 44+ CH 46+ and IE11+.

Comment: @RenevanderLende While i agree that Jessica probably found a bug in the flexbox model, the original question don't mention the use of pseudo-elements in the wrapper like `:after` and `:before`. Those worries are beyond the scope of the original question, and in my opinion should be addressed to the developers of Gecko and Webkit.

Comment: Are you saying it was tested on the those browsers, and worked, or it didn't work?

Comment: @Romulo, I got you, but the ::pseudo was just as an example to prove that your solution works in this particular jsFiddle, while assuming that Jessica's final html would be more sophisticated. I was just looking ahead, but stricktly speaking you are absolutely right, no argument from me.

Comment: @Romulo: in addition: I further assumed, that if LI's are added/removed at runtime while the user scrolls, then resizing would not do the trick. I'm not pickering at all, just doing a lot of assuming (and trying to find the best, failssafe solution).

Comment: @Jessica FF and CH show the same result as your initial problem, while IE doesn't, but all three browser don't update the scrollbar's thumb position. Be warned though, Romulo's solution does work for your final jsFiddle, but should you add/remove LI's on the fly, it will no longer.

Answer (score 0):

remove align-content and use `margin-left:20%; margin-right:auto;`

Comment: That doesn't center it. I'm not sure you completely understand the issue here. What I want is the right and left side of the `ul` to always have the same amount of distance from the browser window.

Comment: means, you don't want any kind of overflow?

Comment: I want the overflow. The problem with my JSFiddle, was that the left side got completely cut off.

Comment: The whole problem is the matter of width of li you provided. Do you want to use width in %?

Comment: Because px is the absolute sizing. It will not care of your screen width.

Comment: Actually, try using big percentages, like 50%. The same problem is still there.

Comment: Jessica, you will try to move across screen size, when you will use 50% as li width. My suggestion is that, you better use less content in a row with flex-basis value. And provide a proper width in percentage. Everything would be fine.

Comment: My point was, that it doesn't fix the problem, it just goes around the problem. (Well, it doesn't completely go around it.)

Answer (score 0):

There is the `safe` keyword to center and keep on-screen. It is only supported on Firefox currently:

```css
ul {
  align-content: safe center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was to give the parent element a set `min-width` that covers all the contents.