# Top of modal gets cut off in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

While there are many questions asking about using flexbox and vertical centering, none of them seem to take into account a fixed position wrapper. Consider the following:

```
.modal-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

.modal-content {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
```

If you fill `.modal-content` with enough content to cause a vertical scrollbar, you will only be able to scroll **down** and the content in the top of the modal will be cut off.

Demo of problem: http://s.codepen.io/graygilmore/debug/3ff624cb89760c3469f286443f1c726a

This can be solved by removed the `fixed` attribute but that only raises a new issue of the `.modal-wrapper` not spanning enough of a height when the content is too small to cause a scrollbar.

Why can I scroll to the bottom of the modal and yet the top of it gets cut off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `margin: 0 auto` on the `.modal-content` flex item, use `margin: auto`.

See my answer here for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33455342/3597276

Comment: I wish that answer made more sense but I'll take it.

Comment: Which part is unclear?

Comment: Oh just flexbox's usage of `margin: auto;`. It's not particularly intuitive and I'll need to do a little bit of reading there.

Comment: @graygilmore, I updated my answer to a similar question. It provides more details and may help you better understand the issue. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33455342/3597276