# Image centered on Firefox but cutoff on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, flexbox

```css
img {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<body style="margin: 0px;">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/I3gA11r.jpg">
</body>
```

When trying the code on both Firefox and Chrome, you're gonna be able to scroll the whole image with Firefox but not with Chrome.

Is the css correct or is it a chrome/webkit bug ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this simple alternative:

```css
body { display: flex; }

img { margin: auto; }
```

```html
<body style="margin: 0px;">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/I3gA11r.jpg">
</body>
```

For a detailed explanation, see: [Can't scroll to top of flex item that is overflowing container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33454533/3597276)

---

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, use [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). More browser compatibility details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276).*