# How to display centered div from top?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this code:

```
<div id="background">
  <div id="box">
    <ol>
    <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
    ...
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
#background {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}
#box {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tfuu63et/

It works fine, if the list is short. But if this is long, I can't see some items on the top of the list.

How can I repair that?

Comment: Have you tried [`align-items: flex-start`](https://jsfiddle.net/tfuu63et/1/)?

Comment: full explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33454533/3597276

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `align-items: flex-start`? That seems to get the results you want.

Unless you're going to be using `flex` more extensively you could also just remove `display: flex;` and `align-items` and the list will still be centered in the page and start at the first list item.

### Old Answer

<strike>**Option 1**</strike>

```
#background {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flext-start;
  height: 100%;
}
```

<strike>**Option 2**</strike>

```
#background {
  height: 100%;
}
```

### Updated Answer

You could use CSS tables.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
#background {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
}
#box {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
    <ol id="box">
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>asdf asdf asdf</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tfuu63et/2/).

Comment: Yes, but if the list is short I want to have this in the middle.

Comment: Ah, okay. That wasn't super clear to me in the question. I'll see what I can do. Is it just going to be this list on the page? Are you looking for vertical **and** horizontal centering?

Answer (score 0):

Just omit align-items, you don't need it to get the desired look:

```
#background {
  display: flex;
  // align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Also you can use `margin-top:50%` on box class, you can change the value as your wish