# CSS: How to avoid scretching container vertically?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I have a flex container, with few `li` elements inside. While adding more `li` elements inside, the container scretches together in above and down sides. I don't want it to move any further in up, only in down direction.

You can check it on my [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yne301hf/)

Try to add few `li` elements, you will see that container is scretching. How to block it?

Comment: Is the goal here to ensure that the container is always accessible via scroll?

Comment: You may be looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33454533/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B Thanks bud, but if you check the jsfiddle there u can see that while adding the text, it scretches vertically together to up and down sides :(

Comment: Yes, it does that because you have `align-items: center` on the container, which *vertically centers* the flex items. If you just want it to expand downward, remove that and use a margin instead: https://jsfiddle.net/yne301hf/6/

Comment: @Michael_B Its not exactly what I want but thanks a lot tho

Comment: @Patrickkx Initially say you have 3 `li`s and it is horizontally and vertically aligned; now if you add say 2 more dynamically (from a javascript code), and when that happens it should not readjust, instead should be just placed below the existing 3 `li`s. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @kukkuz Exactly my bro

Comment: @Patrickkx have added an answer, could you please check if it answers your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try this out and see if it is what you are going for. If not I may need some additional info.

```
.mainContainer {
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   display: block;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}

.content {
   min-height: 350px;
   width: 300px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   background: #f2f2f2;
   border: 1px #ccc solid;
   position:relative;
   margin:0 auto;
   display:block;
   top:50%;
   margin-top:-25%;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I need :(

Comment: Can you expand on what you are looking for? With the code above the container expands down like you requested and is centered. I am not sure I understand what you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I am using some Jquery here for adding new elements:

1. So I removed `min-height` for `content`
2. Reset the `ul` margin-bottom to zero.
3. The new items are added via JS and are positioned absolutely:

   ```
   ul.list-group {
     margin-bottom: 0;
     position: relative;
   }
   ul .list-group-item.counter{
     position:absolute;
     width: 100%;
   }
   ```

   The new items are listed one below the other giving the `margin-top` property:

   ```
   $('.list-group').append("<li class='list-group-item counter' style='margin-top:" + newItems * 100 + "px'>x</li>");
   ```

Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

```js
var newItems = 0;
$('.fixed_btn').click(function(event) {
  $('.list-group').append("<li class='list-group-item counter' style='margin-top:" + newItems * 100 + "px'>x</li>");
  newItems++;
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
body {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-family: Raleway;
}
.mainContainer {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.content {
  /*min-height: 350px;*/
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
}
.list-group-item {
  height: 100px;
}
ul.list-group {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.fixed_btn {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
ul .list-group-item.counter{
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="content">
    <ul class='list-group'>
      <li class='list-group-item'>x</li>
      <li class='list-group-item'>x</li>
      <li class='list-group-item'>x</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn fixed_btn">+ Add</button>
```

Comment: Looks great my friend, but the problem is... the content doesnt scretch itself while adding new `li` elements. The content box is not flexible, it's just static, not dynamic :(

Answer (score 1):

If you change your `.mainContainer` CSS so that the height is `auto`. Now the list will not move up, but only will move down as you wanted as the height is flexible depending on the content:

```
.mainContainer {
    width: 100vw;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Also, if you change the `.content` CSS so that the `min-height` is `auto` it seems to look nicer when there are fewer `li` elements:

```
.content {
    min-height: auto;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
}
```

Updated (again) [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yne301hf/3/), try to add more `li` elements

If your looking for the list to stay in position, but when more elements are added to have a scroll but still be fixed see this other [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yne301hf/4/)

Comment: It seems to work for me (if I understand your question properly), what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Your solution doesnt stay exactly in the centre of body. And the margin isn't flexible, just static. It has to be 100% dynamic brother

Comment: I'm not sure what your after then, as my solution only moves the list down, and the margin is dynamic when adding more `li` elements

Comment: Yeah, but the container isnt centered vertically at start :( its static.