# Flexbox not respecting full width for overflow

Tags: html, css, scroll, flexbox

I'm working on the layout below:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.tier-1 {
  flex: 0 0 40px;
}

.tier-2 {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  background-color: steelblue;
}

.stuff {
  flex: 1 0 100px;
  background-color: navy;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.block-row {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.block {
  flex: 0 0 470px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

.block.wide {
  flex: 0 0 950px;
  height: 150px;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="tier-1"></div>
<div class="tier-2"></div>
<div class="stuff">
  <div class="block-row">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block-row">
    <div class="block wide"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also can be edited at this Codepen: http://codepen.io/brad_julian/pen/BpzmYy/

The problem is that if the viewport is too skinny, the boxes in the first row are getting cut off.  What I want is for the ".stuff" space to have a horizontal scrollbar when the window is too small.

Any idea why that isn't working?

EDIT: The problem I'm having *is* identical to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454533/cant-scroll-to-top-of-flex-item-that-is-overflowing-container) (except horizontal, not vertical)

Comment: The `justify-content: center` is causing the problem. (If you remove it, the scrollbar works.) You need to use `auto` margins.

Comment: Simply replacing `justify-content: center;` with `margin: 0 auto;` changed the behavior but did not fix the problem.

Comment: Unlike `justify-content`, `auto` margins go on flex items, not the flex container. And only use them on the outer items: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NdrMxj

Comment: The second `.block-row` now overlaps the first if the vertical space is too small.  In addition, the `margin-right` doesn't seem to reserve enough space while the left side does.

Comment: MDN has a good explanation of this behavior. See the duplicate post.

Comment: I was able to fix the overlap between rows, but the right edge of my boxes being smack against the window edge seems to be an unfixable problem.  I don't like that behavior, but it's better than what I had.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Consider using a right-side padding on the container.