# Can't scroll to top with modal and overlay with display flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a modal with a backdrop overlay, this is my example:

https://codepen.io/tyrellrummage/full/XeRQYm/

(make the window smaller to see the top and bottom overflow).

Basically the structure is:

```
<div class="overlay">
    <div class="modal">
        //content
    </div>
</div>
```

and the current styling:

```
.overlay{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.modal{
    margin: 4rem 0;
}
```

this works for the bottom part of the modal, but the top part gets trimmed (cut out). How can I fix this only with CSS?

Comment: You need to add `.overlay{ padding: 4rem 0;overflow-y:auto;box-sizing: border-box;} .modal{ margin: auto 0;}` to your CSS to apply Michael_B's solution ([pen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aLWeKZ).). Another option is to check if `.modal`'s height is smaller than `.overlay`'s and adjust the `align-items` property: `if(document.querySelector('.overlay').clientHeight < document.querySelector('.overlay > .modal').clientHeight){document.querySelector('.overlay').style = 'align-items: flex-start;';}`  @Michael_B: it's not an ***exact*** duplicate. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks actually I used `align-items: flex-start` and it worked. If you want, answer it and I'll mark as correct.

Comment: Duplicate questions can't be answered. But it's ok, don't worry. Michael is, in principle, right. Your question ***is*** a duplicate. The reason I said it is not an **exact** duplicate is because you also need to know to apply `box-sizing:border-box` to `.overflow`, which requires a decent level of CSS knowledge. In terms of being helpful to future visitors, your question is on the edge between being a duplicate and deserving its own, proper, answer. It's debatable.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, go ahead and post a proper answer. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33454533/3597276

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very thorough explanation on why this happens can be read [in this awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33455342/1891677).

Applied to your case, you need both `top` and `bottom` margins of `.modal` set to `auto`.

Which means you need to place the `4rem` margins as `padding`s of `.overlay`.

Which, in turn, means you need to also apply `box-sizing:border-box` to it, so the paddings are subtracted from height, not added, resulting in:

```css
.modal { 
  margin: auto 0;
}
.overlay{ 
  padding: 4rem 0;
  overflow-y:auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Nice! btw, adding padding 4rem 0 to the container works but now the bottom is cut out