# How to use safe center with flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

Centred flexbox items can have undesirable behaviour [when they overflow their container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454533/cant-scroll-to-top-of-flex-item-that-is-overflowing-container).

Several non-flex solutions have been provided for this issue, but [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) there is a `safe` value which is described as follows.

> If the size of the item overflows the alignment container, the item is instead aligned as if the alignment mode were start.

It can be used as follows.

```
align-items: safe center;
```

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any examples or discussions of this, or determine how much browser support there is for it.

I have attempted to use `safe` [in this CodePen](https://codepen.io/ChrisTalman/pen/dZrWqz). However, it doesn't work for me. The `safe` seems to be ignored, or perhaps the container element is improperly styled.

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could shed some light on `safe` and whether and how it can be used to solve the overflow problem, as demonstrated by the CodePen example.

Comment: Rachel Andrew discusses safe alignment in this [smashing magazine article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/09/overflow-data-loss-css/#data-loss-and-alignment) There is also a [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/rachelandrew/pen/QWLMrpE) there. By the way: currently safe alignment works on firefox

Comment: `center safe` works in Chrome 84

Comment: No, `center safe` does not work in Chrome.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The newer keyword [`safe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content#safe) *still* has bad browser support, so to get the same effect, cross browser, use [auto margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins) for now, which should be set on the flex item.

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZaPJbv)

*Note, to compensate for the `modal`'s 50px top/bottom margin, use `padding` on `modal-container`.*

```
.modal-container
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;                /*  changed  */
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 50px 0;                        /*  added  */
  box-sizing: border-box;                 /*  added  */
}
.modal-container > #modal
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto 0;                         /*  changed  */
  padding: 12px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`safe` isn't implemented in most browsers yet. You can recreate some of its functionality with auto margins.

I was trying to use `justify-content: safe center` to have a bunch of items centered in a footer when the viewport was wide, but have them able to scroll without clipping off the left side when the viewport was small.

When I tried to fix this with auto margins as Ason suggested, it did fix the clipping, but it also spread the items out evenly, which isn't what I wanted.

I found I could simulate safe center in this context by applying auto margins to only the first and last elements.

Assuming my flex items have class "item":

```
.item:first-child {
    margin-left: auto;
}
.item:last-child {
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

[CodePen with examples comparing each solution](https://codepen.io/saintofroc/pen/NWNrWzQ?editors=1100)

Comment: The margin trick does not work in IE 11. For older browser support, you can simply use a table instead. Here is a demo on jsbin: https://output.jsbin.com/kejiquz, for testing browser compatibility on ie browserstack. To edit demo, go here: https://jsbin.com/kejiquz/1/edit?html,css,output). PS: Demo is about vertical centering, not horizontal, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Use `align-items: flex-start;` instead of using it with the safe keyword, Also, you can add `margin/padding` to get the desired behavior for the same.