# Using overflow-x: scroll with justify-content: center hides the earlier blocks

Tags: css, flexbox

I have to use the justify-content: center to center the block to come in the center of their parent div. And if the content are more than it needs to be fit in the width, I need to use overflow-x: scroll so that all the blocks come in same line. The problem is some of the starting blocks get hidden using justify-content: center;

Note: I need to have all the content in the center if the number of blocks are limited to 3 or 4 or smaller number.

Please go through this link

```css
.nav-tabs {
        overflow-x: scroll;
        border: 0;
        display: flex;
        align-items: stretch;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .nav-tabs .nav-item {
        width: 20%;
        min-width: 198px;
        float: left;
        display: flex;
        align-items: stretch;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-1">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 1</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-2">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 2</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-3">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 3</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-1">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 1</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-2">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 2</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-3">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 3</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-1">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 1</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-2">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 2</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-3">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 3</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-1">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 1</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-2">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 2</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-3">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 3</span>
   </a>
  </li>
  
  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-1">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 1</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-2">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 2</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-3">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 3</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-1">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 1</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-2">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 2</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-3">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 3</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-1">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 1</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-2">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 2</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-3">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 3</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-1">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 1</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-2">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 2</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-3">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 3</span>
   </a>
  </li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't scroll to top of flex item that is overflowing container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454533/cant-scroll-to-top-of-flex-item-that-is-overflowing-container)

Comment: No it is not the same. The solution had removed the justify-content: center; to unknown xjustfiy-content: center; which makes it not centered with flex css.

Comment: It is, it use auto margin to center, and that is how you need to do here, as their is no other way

Comment: Another possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47635911/how-to-use-safe-center-with-flexbox/47636238#47636238 ... where the new `safe` keyword will solve this, though it is not well supported yet

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need wrap the `ul` under a container. Please see my codepen [here](https://codepen.io/umeshmanglani/pen/rgYgyz). I also pasted code here.

```css
.nav-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.nav-tabs {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-item {
  width: 20%;
  min-width: 198px;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
<ul class="nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-1">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 1</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-2">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 2</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-3">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 3</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-1">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 1</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-2">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 2</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-3">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 3</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-1">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 1</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-2">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 2</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-3">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 3</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-1">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 1</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-2">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 2</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-3">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 3</span>
   </a>
  </li>
  
  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-1">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 1</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-2">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 2</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-3">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 3</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-1">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 1</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-2">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 2</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-3">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 3</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-1">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 1</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-2">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 2</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-3">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 3</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-1">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 1</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-2">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 2</span>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab-3">
    <span class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></span>
    <span class="iconText">TAB 3</span>
   </a>
  </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If you add justify-content: center; to the nav-container then you will see the issue I believe the original post mentions. It is the same issue I'm having. Many of the nav-items at the beginning of the ul are hidden and unable to scroll into visibility.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve correct scrolling of children when there are no space and at the same time center them when there are free space, you could leave **block** type for container and **inline-flex** type for children.

```css
.nav {
  background: lightblue;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-item {
  background: pink;
  width: 20%;
  min-width: 198px;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<h2>Case 1: not enough space</h2>
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        TAB 1
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        TAB 2
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        TAB 3
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        TAB 4
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        TAB 5
    </li>
</ul>

<h2>Case 2: extra space</h2>

<ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        TAB 1
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        TAB 2
    </li>
</ul>
```