# Flexbox content not showing properly

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I like to have a div that keeps all it's children in the center (vertical and horizontal). I can easily achieve this by using flexbox. But when width of  my children get bigger than the parent, a part of children is not visible.

How can I fix this?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ariannargesi/pen/OJzGdBy)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
   height: 500px;
   width: 500px;
   background: red;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   overflow: scroll;
}
.children {
   min-width: 1200px;
   height: 50px;
   background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="children">
    <h1>Welcome to my city, california</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because you flexbox is smaller than the child , it still tries to center the child and make it overflow on both sides. You can avoid this using the keyword `safe` :    `justify-content: safe center;` or drop it and use margin on the child instead.

Comment: have you read my earlier comment? did it fix something ? ... also, remove that min-width and let your *dynamic* child to size itself. ... if  it is dynamic but at least 1200px , there won't be much to see happen for short texts.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus ```justify-content: safe center;``` didn't fix it. Actually had no effect

Comment: okay, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47635911/how-to-use-safe-center-with-flexbox This is not yet avalaible in every browsers.  .what about min-width ?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the `justify-content` to be `flex-start`

See below.

And if you want the H1 to be centered, just use `text-align: center`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
   height: 500px;
   width: 500px;
   background: red;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-start;
   align-items: center;
  overflow: scroll;
   
}
.children {
   min-width: 1200px;
   height: 50px;
   background: blue;

}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="children">
    <h1>Welcome to my city, california</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like to keep the children at the center. so if you add flex-start content will stick to left if children is smaller than parent

Comment: The point is my children is really dynamic. It's not a h1 all the time. It should be stable in all situations

Comment: Ok well the answer to your question is that the child with justify-content being set to center, while in a overflow: scroll container, will appear off the screen. I'd suggest coming up with a more semantic HTML markup then.

Comment: So it's not possible with current structure right?

Comment: With your current structure, if you must keep the CSS the same, you could use JavaScript to dynamically change the width, if it truly is dynamic. Otherwise, if you have a 500px container, and a child content that could be 1200px, what do you expect it to do? You could maybe just set all children to be max-width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; to be centered.

Comment: The JS function would just compare the children width to the parent width, and if its bigger, then dont justify-content center. Make sense?

Comment: Yes. totally make sense. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

*Change the*
 .container{
min-width: 100%}

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
   height: 500px;
   width: 500px;
   background: red;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   overflow: scroll;
}
.children {
   min-width: 100%;
   height: 50px;
   background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="children">
    <h1>Welcome to my city, california</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No. You changed the width of children to 100%. I don't want this