# How to enable a scrollbar on a flex item?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flexbox-based layout with two panels (top and bottom) occupying 1/3 and 2/3 of the viewport, respectively. (Actually there are more panels, but I've distilled it to the minimal example).

The top panel is also a flex container, because I want its children to flow top to bottom and be vertically centered when there is room. When there is more stuff in top panel than would fit in it, I want it to be scrollable, hence `overflow: auto`.

The problem: the contents of `top` shrink to its size, even with `flex-shrink: 0`, and the scrollbar never pops up.

Observe how the `content` is shrunk in the following demo, even though it has an explicitly specified height:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.main {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.top {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-basis: 33%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    overflow: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 20px;
}

.bottom {
    overflow: auto;
    flex-basis: 67%;
}

.content {
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="content">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

The questions:

1. **How to fix this while preserving the layout requirements?** Disabling `display: flex` for the top panel gives the desired effect in the demo. I *could* position contents of `top` in a flexboxless way, but I lose the benefits of flex layout and the automatic vertical centering.
2. **Why does this happen?** References to CSS spec would be welcome.

Comment: also give it a max-height of your flex-basis it happens as flex basis is like an initial setting so it only says start at the point and then can change size according to content,  I find flex-basis never works as I intend it to so barely use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

> The problem: the contents of `top` shrink to its size, even with `flex-shrink: 0`, and the scrollbar never pops up.

Actually, the solution is `flex-shrink: 0`. So the question becomes, where did you apply it?

It wouldn't work if you applied it to `top` – a flex item in the primary container with `flex-basis: 33%` (i.e., `height: 33%`, in this case) – because the length of `top` is a percentage. As such, it will shrink / expand naturally as percentage lengths are relative to the parent container.

You need to apply `flex-shrink: 0` to `.content` – a flex item in the nested container with a fixed height (`height: 500px` / `flex-basis: 500px`).

So this will work:

```
.content {
    height: 500px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

or this:

```
.content {
    flex-basis: 500px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

or, better yet, this:

```
.content {
    flex: 0 0 500px;  /* don't grow, don't shrink, stay fixed at 500px */
}
```

From the spec:

> [**7.2. Components of
>   Flexibility**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-components)
>
> Authors are encouraged to control flexibility using the `flex` shorthand
>   rather than with its longhand properties directly, as the shorthand
>   correctly resets any unspecified components to accommodate [common
>   uses](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;  
}

.top {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 33%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.bottom {
  overflow: auto;
  flex-basis: 67%;
}

.content {
  flex: 0 0 500px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="content">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

---

Then you have **a second problem**, which is that the upper section of the `top` element gets cut off and is inaccessible via scroll. This is caused by `justify-content: center` on the container.

This is a known issue. It is solved by using flex `auto` margins.

So instead of this:

```
.top {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-basis: 33%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    overflow: auto;
    /* justify-content: center;  <--- REMOVE */
    padding: 20px;
}
```

do this:

```
.content {
  flex: 0 0 500px;
  margin: auto 0; /*  top & bottom auto margins */
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.top {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 33%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: auto; 
  /* justify-content: center;  USE AUTO MARGINS ON FLEX ITEM INSTEAD */
  padding: 20px;
}

.bottom {
  overflow: auto;
  flex-basis: 67%;
}

.content {
  flex: 0 0 500px;
  margin: auto 0;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="content">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Here's a complete explanation:

- [Can't scroll to top of flex item that is overflowing container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33454533/3597276)

Answer (score 0):

The scrollbar appears when there are enough `.content` element shrinked to their very minimal height (one line height in this case).

That's not really how things work with flex. `height` is not strictly respected. If you still want to work with `height`, you can fix this by setting a `min-height` to `.content` according to the minimum height you want for them.

Or you can instead set `flex` on `.content` (and get rid of `height`):
`css
flex: 100px 1 0;`

Which will set a minimum height (flex-basis) of 100px, flex-grow at 1 so that it takes all the available space, and flex-shrink at 0 so that the element is always at least 100px tall.