# overflow-y either auto or scroll bar does not allow showing all overflow content

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a dummy screen with background image.  The background image correctly expands or contracts with the size of the viewport.  I have dummy flexbox content that I intentionally make overflow the bottom of the page.
The scrollbar correctly appears, **but it will not scroll far enough to show all the content that overflowed.**
Apologies: the content is varied so I can tell what IS NOT showing.
Dummy header menu bar is fine.. it is supposed to scroll up - and it does.

CSS:

```
    html  {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;

  margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; cursor: default
}

ul {
  list-style: none;

  li {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
}

.blockStyleEven {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  color: white;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.blockSpaceAround {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  color: white;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.blockSpaceBetween {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  color: white;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.blockStart {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  color: white;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.blockEnd {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  color: white;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.blockCenter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  color: white;
  justify-content: center;
}

.maroon {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: maroon;
}

.red {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.workspace {
  background: url("././Features.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;

  h1 {
    color: #E0B228;
  }

  h2 {
    color: #2856E0;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'width': '100vw', 'height': '100vh'}">
  <div [ngStyle]="{'display': 'flex', 'flex-direction': 'column'}">
    <div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': 'beige'}">
      <ul>
        <li>First</li>
        <li>Second</li>
        <li>Third</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div  class="workspace">
      <div class="blockStyleEven">
        <div class="maroon">space-evenly</div>
        <div class="red">RED</div>
        <div class="green">GREEN</div>
        <div class="blue">BLUE</div>
      </div>
      <div class="blockSpaceAround">
        <div class="maroon">space-around</div>
        <div class="red">RED</div>
        <div class="green">GREEN</div>
        <div class="blue">BLUE</div>
      </div>
      <div class="blockSpaceBetween">
        <div class="maroon">space-between</div>
        <div class="red">RED</div>
        <div class="green">GREEN</div>
        <div class="blue">BLUE</div>
      </div>
      <div class="blockStart">
        <div class="maroon">start</div>
        <div class="red">RED</div>
        <div class="green">GREEN</div>
        <div class="blue">BLUE</div>
      </div>
      <div class="blockEnd">
        <div class="maroon">end</div>
        <div class="red">RED</div>
        <div class="green">GREEN</div>
        <div class="blue">BLUE</div>
      </div>
      <div class="blockCenter">
        <div class="maroon">center</div>
        <div class="red">RED</div>
        <div class="green">GREEN</div>
        <div class="blue">BLUE</div>
      </div>
      <div class="blockStyleEven">
        <div class="maroon">space-evenly</div>
        <div class="red">RED</div>
        <div class="green">GREEN</div>
        <div class="blue">BLUE</div>
      </div>
      <div class="blockSpaceAround">
        <div class="maroon">space-around</div>
        <div class="red">RED</div>
        <div class="green">GREEN</div>
        <div class="blue">BLUE</div>
      </div>
      <div class="blockSpaceBetween">
        <div class="maroon">space-between</div>
        <div class="red">RED</div>
        <div class="green">GREEN</div>
        <div class="blue">BLUE</div>
      </div>
      <div class="blockStart">
        <div class="maroon">start</div>
        <div class="red">RED</div>
        <div class="green">GREEN</div>
        <div class="blue">BLUE</div>
      </div>
      <div class="blockEnd">
        <div class="maroon">end</div>
        <div class="red">RED</div>
        <div class="green">GREEN</div>
        <div class="blue">BLUE</div>
      </div>
      <div class="blockCenter">
        <div class="maroon">center</div>
        <div class="red">RED</div>
        <div class="green">GREEN</div>
        <div class="blue">BLUE</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.
Yogi

Comment: have you looked at this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454533/cant-scroll-to-top-of-flex-item-that-is-overflowing-container

Comment: Can you please make a plunkr for this?

Comment: `[ngStyle]` so you edit every style line by hand?

Comment: no I don't style every line by hand, but I can copy and paste a dumb example really fast without any effort.

Comment: Give me a hint: I know how to make a plnkr but how do I link it to this question... just save it to some link and put the link here in the comments?? Or does stackoverflow have a way? Yogi

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.  The problem was the scrollbar was "too short" to show all the content.  This was because my workspace class was on a div below the dummy menu bar.  When I put the workspace (containing Margin: auto) on the outer move div, it worked perfectly.
Thanks for all your help.
Apologies for the earlier poor formatting, which has now been cleaned up.
Yogi

Comment: so just add margin:auto?