# Overflow not visible for centered flex item

Tags: css, flexbox

In the code snipped below, I have an item that I centered using flexbox. There is a clear top and bottom border, but as you can see, the top border is cut off when `align-items` is set to `center`.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: skyblue;
  border-top: 10px solid red;
  border-bottom: 10px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

If I change `align-items` to `flex-start`, you can now scroll the entire container and see both the top and bottom border:

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: skyblue;
  border-top: 10px solid red;
  border-bottom: 10px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Why does this happen? I would like to have the container centered in its parent while being able to scroll the entire length of it if it overflows.

Here is a link to the code on CodePen as well: https://codepen.io/robkom/pen/WyyQZa.

Comment: Found the same question here and figured it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454533/cant-scroll-to-top-of-flex-item-that-is-overflowing-container