# Hidden content in Chrome with Flexbox horizontally centered layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Based on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically) i'm trying to center horizontally a content with flex css, and usually it goes right. But when the content is very large the left part goes hidden. It happens in Chrome, and the horizontal scrollbar doesn't help. As you can see in the snippet. What I have to change to get it right?

```css
.flex-container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.row {
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid blue;

}
.flex-item {
    background-color: tomato;
    padding: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap; /* added to simulate large content */
    margin: 0px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="flex-item">hidden.............................somewhere.....................................................................................................end</div>
        <div class="flex-item">where</div>
        <div class="flex-item">I</div>
        <div class="flex-item">am?</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

As you can see, this is a different formulation of this problem with flexbox: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454533/cant-scroll-to-top-of-flex-item-that-is-overflowing-container)

Comment: Your flex-items are no such thing since they do not have a flex-parent.

Comment: Is this what you are after - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dqxdNz

Comment: Paulie sorry your codepen doesn't work. Works only in a large screen.

Comment: Then you need to explain in detail the issue because its not clear.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try following code.**

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.row {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
.flex-item {
    background-color: tomato;
    margin: 0px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: left;
    max-width: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="flex-item">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
        <div class="flex-item">where</div>
        <div class="flex-item">I</div>
        <div class="flex-item">am?</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, you changed too much. I want to preserve the flexbox justify-content: center;

Comment: Ok no proble but i just try resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flex-container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item {
    background-color: tomato;
    padding: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap; /* added to simulate large content */
    margin: 0px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">

        <div class="flex-item">hidden.............................somewhere.......................................................................................................</div>
        <div class="flex-item">where</div>
        <div class="flex-item">I</div>
        <div class="flex-item">am?</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Sorry your solution change the result but the first letters of the first word appears cut in half.