# Why is display flex hiding first image in a row?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a row of thumbnails that I want: centered, if they are smaller than the window; and scrollable, if they are bigger than the window.

It's almost working. However, part of the first image disappears to the left of the screen. If I have even more images, the first ones completely disappear. What am I doing wrong?

```css
.container {
  background-color:green;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}
.box {
  background-color:red;
  margin:0.5vh;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
  <div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
  <div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
  <div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
  <div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
  <div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
  <div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
  <div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of .container {  justify-content:center; } which is the culprit, you want .container {  justify-content: - any of the other options }

Comment: @CarolMcKay if I have, say, 3 images, what other option will put the images in the center, spaced only by their margins?

Comment: Ooooh I'll think upon that.

Comment: Try `justify-content: space-around`

Comment: I don't think there's a clean solution to this problem yet. You may need to use a script to switch the alignment to flex-start once there's an overflow. In the meanwhile, this may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33454533/3597276

Comment: @HariniP It's a good idea to read the other comments before submitting your own.

Comment: Do you need to use flex? http://jsfiddle.net/8u7vh061/1

Comment: @Pete Thanks for thinking outside the (flex)box. It works perfectly! Will you add this as an answer, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need flex - you can use inline block and white space nowrap:

```css
.container {
  background-color: green;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  line-height:0;       /* make bottom padding same as top padding by removing line-height */
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5vh;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div><!--
  
     please note I comment out white space between elements for equal padding

--><div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div><!--
  --><div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div><!--
  --><div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div><!--
  --><div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div><!--
  --><div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div><!--
  --><div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div><!--
  --><div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div><!--
--></div>
```

Comment: That solved my problem, at least (shame on flex). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

#### Reason

The reason is that your boxes are more than the container `width` and your container has no `flex-wrap: wrap;` (The default value is `no-wrap`) So the boxes cannot wrap and as your container is a `display: flex` its `width` won't increase with its children (the boxes) and it will behave like block and just fills the screen.

#### Solution

Try `display: inline-flex` instead. As it behaves same is `inline` elements, its `width` will grow to fit its children `width`.

Here's a working example based on your code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.container {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0.5vh;
}

.box img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
      <div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
      <div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
      <div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
      <div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
      <div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
      <div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
      <div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
      <div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
      <div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
      <div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
      <div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

#### why not `inline-block`?

Because it will not remove the space between the boxes and you have to stick the box elements to each other like this:

```
<div class='box'></div><!-- no extra white space here --><div class='box'></div>
```

You may use `float` to fix this problem or decrease the `font-size` of container which aren't as good as `inline-flex` solution.

Also note that although `inline-block` may work for you, it's not an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container-container {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
 }

.container {
  background-color:green;
  display:flex;
  /* remove center alignment from inner container but leave display:flex
  -- justify-content:center; */
 /* change overflow-x to auto so we don't have to see it until we need it   -- overflow-x:scroll; */
  overflow-x:auto; /* now overflow auto */
  overflow-y:hidden;
}
.box {
  background-color:red;
  margin:0.5vh;
}
/* bright pink border on the first box to demonstrate it worked */
.firstbox {
   border:6px solid hotpink;
}
/* blue border on the last box to demonstrate if it shows up */
.lastbox {
   border:6px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- add an extra wrapper with display flex and your center alignment -->
 <div class='container-container'>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='box firstbox'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
  <div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
  <div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- add an extra wrapper with display flex and your center alignment -->
   <div class='container-container'>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='box firstbox'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
  <div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
  <div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
  <div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
  <div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
  <div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
  <div class='box'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
  <div class='box lastbox'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouGarden/Web/100x100/510187.jpg' /></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yuck, the scrollbar is too low

Comment: I had to add a `bottom:0` so that this div wouldn't go to the top of the screen. Then I don't see the scrollbar. I also had to add a `right:0` so that it would fill the whole screen, then it just returned to the first error.

Comment: please see flex and position changes @Rodrigo - another possible solution