# CSS Grid looks fine on Firefox but not on Chrome or Safari

Tags: css, css-grid, grid-layout

My layout looks as I expect in Firefox, but not in Safari or Chrome.

The white header element should be above the photo, not overlapping it.

CodePen Example: https://codepen.io/ivanoats/pen/byvXdq

HTML:

```
<header role="banner">
<div class="logo">
  <div class="logotype">Good&nbsp;❖&nbsp;Paddle</div>
</div>
<nav class="main-nav">
  <input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle">
  <label for="menu-toggle" class="label-toggle"></label>
  <nav class="nav-wrapper">
    <ul role="navigation">
      <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</nav>
</header>
<div class="container">
 <section class="hero">
   <h1>What makes a good paddle?</h1>
   <h2>
     <a href="#">Let me know</a>
   </h2>
   <img src="https://goodpaddle.com/images/semiahmoo.jpg" alt="pic of good stroke">
   <p>Blade fin unlimited waves leash catch fin valve. Laird PFD aloha whitewater SUP dana point sesh kook foil, PFD board
    bag downwind dana point PFD..</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
 }

html {
  font-kerning: normal;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ol,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, Helvetica, Arial,
  sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 20%);
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 5vw;
  margin-right: 5vw;
}

.main-nav {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.nav-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  padding: 0;
}


.main-nav ul li {
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav ul li a {
  color: #000;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

.logo {
     width: 15%;
  }

}

```
.hero {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 1 / 6;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.hero img {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
  object-fit: fill;
  opacity: 0.85;
}

.hero p {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: 4 / 5;
  align-self: center;
  width: 66%;
  justify-self: center;
  font-size: calc(0.75rem + 1vw);
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
}


.content {
  grid-column: 2 / 5;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  min-height: 200px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

What am I doing wrong, or how should I fix it for the currently available versions of Chrome and Safari?

Comment: Your question will no longer be useful for future visitors as soon as you fix the issue on your website. If you need a developer to fix your website, hire one. If you want to ask a question from which anyone with a similar issue might learn, please follow the recommendations in [ask]. In short, provide a [mcve] inside the question itself, which is not prone to change after the question has been answered. That is to say: most people who you want to have a look at your issue will not open the website on general principles.

Comment: your `grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 20%);` seems to be the issue not supported currently or not implemented correctly in Chrome. try altering that or vendor prefixing different code on it.

Comment: @Rikin, it's not that, it's `align-items: center`. It should be `align-items: safe center`. At core, it's a duplicate of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454533/cant-scroll-to-top-of-flex-item-that-is-overflowing-container) and it's a shared problem between overflowing centered children, regardless of axis or centering method. The proposed solution for `grid` and `flexbox` is adding "`safe`" to the alignment term, but it's not yet widely adopted.

Comment: Thanks @AndreiGheorghiu for the feedback. I have made a codepen and will update the question: https://codepen.io/ivanoats/pen/byvXdq

Comment: use some framework like bootstrap, build a solid grid system is a struggle, you will find bugs after bugs writing on your own :)

Comment: Consider focusing on two issues (both touched upon above): (1) You're setting your row heights to 20%. But there's no parent reference, so the rule fails. The row heights you set are not working in any browser. (2) `align-items: center` is  misaligning your layout. I'll post two duplicates that will explain more.

Comment: For people marking as a dup please explain why instead of just punting, it would be so much more helpful.

Comment: @Michael_B please explain why duplicate

Comment: I specifically explained why in my comment to your question. I didn't simply post the duplicates or "punt". I wrote my rationale first. The duplicates further expound on my two points.