# CSS Overflow Scrolls Only One Direction

Tags: css, scroll, overflow

I have a Web page where the CSS overflow is set to auto. The scroll bar appears when overflow occurs, but it lets me scroll only to the right. It won't scroll left, so there's no way to see the clipped portion on the left side. NOTE: This is not a duplicate of other posts dealing with *vertical* scrolling. My problem is with *horizontal* scrolling.

The URL:

http://www.hymntime.com/tch/bio/h/a/v/havergal_fr.htm

The HTML:

```
<div id="preface">
    <div>
        <figure><img alt="portrait" src="../../../../img/h/a/v/havergal_fr3.jpg"></figure>
    </div>
    <div style="min-width: 15em;">
        <p id="birth">De­cem­ber 14, 1836, 
            <span class="map" onclick='show("Astley,Worcestershire DY13,UK")'>Ast­ley</span>, Wor­ces­ter­shire, Eng­land.
        </p>
        <p id="death">June 3, 1879, 
            <span class="map" onclick='show("Caswell Bay,UK")'>Cas­well Bay</span> (near Swan­sea), Wales.
        </p>
        <p id="burial">
            <span class="map" onclick='show("52.306124,-2.312777")'>Pri­ory Church of St. Pe­ter</span>, Ast­ley, Wor­ces­ter­shire, Eng­land. On her tomb­stone was the Scrip­ture verse she claimed as her own:
        </p>
        <blockquote>
            <p>The blood of Je­sus Christ cleans­eth us from all sin.<br>1 John 1:7</p>
        </blockquote>
    </div>
    <div>
        <figure><img alt="portrait" src="../../../../img/h/a/v/havergal_fr_4.jpg"></figure>
    </div>
    <div>
        <figure><img alt="portrait" src="../../../../img/h/a/v/havergal_fr_2.jpg"></figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

The style sheet:

```
#preface {
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    display:  flex;
    overflow: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 2ex;
    padding-bottom: 2ex;
 }
#preface .copyright, preface .license { text-align: center; }
#preface > div > p { margin: 1em; }
#preface figure { margin-left: .5em; margin-right: .5em; }
#preface img  { border: 8px ridge silver; border-radius: 20px; }
#preface ul { padding-left: 3em; }
.preface-text {min-width: 15em}

}
```

I'm new to using flex boxes, so I suspect I've made a simple mistake, but I can't see what's wrong.

Comment: Hi, your site scroll up and down without problem, where do you need to scroll left and right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't scroll to top of flex item that is overflowing container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454533/cant-scroll-to-top-of-flex-item-that-is-overflowing-container)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css in id `#preface` at your website change `width: 100%` to `width: fit-content;`, it should solve your problem.

When you are using width:100% the element will be the same width as its parent element. 
In your case the parent is the body and when you zoom in with the +/- buttons the body width changes according to the font size and not his child elements.

Comment: I added **width: fit-content** to the style sheet, but it had no effect. Still can't scroll left. In fact, in the Firefox Responsive Design Mode (Firefox version 68.0.1, 64-bit), the debugger says *width: fit-content** is an "invalid property value". I don't know why, since I see references to that value on multiple Web sites.

Answer (score 1):

If a **centered** child overflows a parent with `overflow: auto` (or `scroll`), the browser won't allow you to scroll to the child's left (or top, on vertical overflow) limit.

This has to do with normal scroll behavior. If you want a child to extend over the left or the top limit of a parent ***and the parent automatically extends to contain that***, the child doesn't really extend over the limit of the parent, does it?

To fix this, the **only** solutions are

- to make your child not expand the parent.
- or to give up centering as soon as the scrollbar is required.

A decent solution in your case would be:

```css
@media (max-width: 1003px) {
  #preface div[style] {
    max-width: 15em;
  }
  #preface {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
```

Or, if you don't want to wrap contents and prefer the scroll:

```css
@media (max-width: 1003px) {
  #preface {
    justify-content: start;
  }
}
```

The key element here being: when the parent starts being overflown by the child (`1003px` in your case), you either change the alignment so the scroll behaves as you want it or change the way you display the child so it doesn't overflow the parent.

Comment: Thanks! This is the first reply that actually seems plausible.

Is the part about this being "normal scroll behavior" documented anywhere? I searched earlier for something like that, but came up dry.

Comment: If it is, I don't know about it. I used this term for lack of a better one. However you choose to name it, it's about when a child overflows a parent towards left or top. Do you start the scrollable area of the parent where the child begins or where the parent does? And the answer is: where the parent does, or else the child wouldn't overflow the parent, would it? Think of cases where you purposefully place the child outside, like a hidden sidebar, which slides in or, similarly, a hidden top bar.