# Scroll doesn't show the whole list of items

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I have a component with fixed `width` and `height`. I need to show a list of items in it. I used `overflow: scroll;` but it doesn't show the whole list! For instance, if I have 10 items, it doesn't show items 1,2 and maybe half of 3!
I tried all things i found online, such as adding `padding`, `height`, or change it to  `overflow: auto;` but neither worked!

SCSS:

```
.cart-dropdown {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: aqua;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  right: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
  z-index: 10;
  .cart-items {
    padding:10px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 320px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .button {
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

Component:

```
const cartDropdown = ({cartItems}) => {
  const renderCartItem = cartItems => {
    return cartItems.map(item => <CartItem key={item.imageUrl} item={item} />);
  };

  return (
    <div className="cart-dropdown">
      <div className="cart-items">{renderCartItem(cartItems)}</div>
      <div className="button">
        <Button>GO TO CHECKOUT</Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ cartStatus: { cartItems } }) => ({
  cartItems
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(cartDropdown);
```

Comment: Please add code examples so that we can take a look

Comment: @TomEsposito edited :)

Comment: A small js fiddle would be super

Comment: Can you provide a full example? What is your html structure?

Comment: @AmanSeth done :)

Comment: I don't see a fiddle added. Please post the RENDERED HTML and CSS output in the question. While the component and SCSS is great, it's way easier for us to help when you supply the rendered output so we can see what you're actually working with. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @disinfor before I do that, as it takes me a long time and might need to get permission from team-lead, can you please provide me with some idea what could be wrong that scroll doesn't show the whole list?

Comment: No, because we can't see your HTML. I have no idea what your rendered code looks like - what does `renderCartItem(cartItems)` output? Why would you need your team-lead's permission? You don't have to post any code that gives details away - change the text to something generic. We need to see the HTML. View source on your page, copy everything in the from the `return` in your component and then update the markup so you don't have any identifying information.

Answer (score 0):

ok, figured it out, that `flex-direction: column;` in `.cart-items` messed up with the scroller!! I don't know why yet so if anyone knows why that makes scroll not showing all the list please comment it below, thanks :)

Comment: Does it still happen if you do `justify-content: flex-start;` instead of center in `.cart-items` ?

Comment: @Pierre-Yves   PERFECT :) no it doesn't happen anymore, thanks please post it as an answer with detail that way that happens

Comment: it was just a idea at the time. Thought flex centering could mess things up with overflowing content ;) See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454533/cant-scroll-to-top-of-flex-item-that-is-overflowing-container) for an actual answer