# Table in flexbox is out of scroll

Tags: html, css

How can i fix table out of screen if it's inside centered flexbox?

[image]

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-villani-br54c?file=/src/App.js).

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <p>
        1__________ 2______________ 3______________ 4____________ 5----------
        6----------------- 7 ----------- 8 -----------------
      </p>
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <th>Россия</th>
          <th>Великобритания</th>
          <th>Европа</th>
          <th>Длина ступни, см</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>34,534,534,534,534,534,534,534,534,534,5 </td>
          <td>
            3,534,534,534,534,534,534,534,534,534,534,534,534,534,534,534,534,5
          </td>
          <td>36</td>
          <td>23</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

Comment: wrapping your table in a `margin: auto` wrapper will fix the scroll, won't center the content though, might find more answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454533

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the table.

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Set table column width.
Add class flexbox to table container.

```
.flex-div {
  ...
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Add flex-item class to tr, set min-width instead of width.

```
.flex-item {
  ...
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: not working :(  https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-williams-fbzm0?file=/src/App.js

Comment: dont use 100% in width of styled.table