# div with min-width set scroll is cut off to the left

Tags: html, scroll, width, overflow

I'm trying to create a webpage with a single centered div that represents a piece of paper. It is very important that the size of the paper never changes, so it has both the `min-width` and `max-width` properties set:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.paper {
  width: 8.5in;
  min-width: 8.5in;
  max-width: 8.5in;
  height: 11in;
  min-height: 11in;
  max-height: 11in;
  background-color: red;
  border: 10px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="paper"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem is that when the size of the browser window is small (e.g. on mobile), the left side of the div is cut off and cannot be scrolled to.

[image: Example of webpage viewed in small browser window]

How can I make it so that it is possible to scroll to the left edge of the div?

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    div::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 8px;
    }

    div::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        background-color: #f6f6f6;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ddd inset;
    }

    div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background-color: #1E90FF;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

        div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: #FF8C00;
        }
</style>
```

Comment: This doesn't help with the problem I'm having, it just styles the scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

I found that `justify-content: center` caused this issue - left border not visible.

As per https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp

> The justify-content property aligns the flexible container's items when the items do not use all available space on the main-axis (horizontally).

Commenting it, made the left border visible.

```css
body {
  overflow: scroll;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /*justify-content: center;*/
}

.paper {
  width: 8.5in;
  min-width: 8.5in;
  max-width: 8.5in;
  height: 11in;
  min-height: 11in;
  max-height: 11in;
  background-color: red;
  border: 10px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="paper"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can confirm that scroll works after `justify-content` is removed. However, that causes the `div` to no longer be centered :(

Comment: Maybe the issue is that your device display width is less than the width of the div, so when justify-content tries to center, somehow the left border gets out of the display, but that's just a guess. Maybe you can try replacing `in` inches with `%` or `vw`/`vh`, remove the commented line and see if it works properly.

Comment: Ok i found a post with the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454533/cant-scroll-to-top-of-flex-item-that-is-overflowing-container, I will create an answer

Comment: You can check if the div just gets out of display, by translating the div to the right, when the scroll bar reaches left side or just translate it to right without scrolling should also work.

Comment: @thesilican, does that mean my guess was right? ;-)

Comment: yea, easiest solution seems like just use `margin: auto` to center

Comment: Yes I was going to suggest to use `margin: auto`, but wasn't sure if that would work with flex :-)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in another post:
[Can't scroll to top of flex item that is overflowing container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454533/cant-scroll-to-top-of-flex-item-that-is-overflowing-container)

Using `justify-content` causes the div to be snapped to the center of the page, making it impossible to scroll to the left side of the page.

Easiest fix is to use `margin: auto` for centering instead of flexbox:

```css
.paper {
  margin: auto;
  width: 8.5in;
  min-width: 8.5in;
  max-width: 8.5in;
  height: 11in;
  min-height: 11in;
  max-height: 11in;
  background-color: red;
  border: 10px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="paper"></div>
</body>

</html>
```