# Vue, Vuetify, CSS. I can't scroll all the way to the left, is there a way to do it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am working on a Vue component that displays a cinema hall. (the seats in the theater).
I want the seats to be generated dynamically and for each row to be able to have a different amount of seats in it.
This is the component code so far:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-container fluid class="ma-0 pa-0 justify-center" style="height: 100vh">
      <div class="overflow-x-auto mx-3" id="seats">
        <div class="screen mx-auto">
          <p class="text-center">Screen</p>
        </div>

        <div class="seats d-flex flex-column justify-center">
          <v-row
            class="justify-center flex-nowrap ma-0"
            v-for="row in hall"
            :key="row.rowNum"
          >
            <div
              class="seat available text-center"
              v-for="(seat, index) in row.seats"
              v-text="index + 1"
              :key="index"
            ></div>
          </v-row>
        </div>
      </div>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      hall: [
        { rowNum: 1, seats: 30 },
        { rowNum: 2, seats: 15 },
        { rowNum: 3, seats: 14 },
        { rowNum: 4, seats: 20 },
        { rowNum: 5, seats: 25 },
        { rowNum: 6, seats: 30 },
        { rowNum: 7, seats: 35 },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

```css
<style lang="css">
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
}

.screen {
  background-color: #2b6282;
  width: 63vw;
}

.screen p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.seats {
  margin-top: 3rem;
  height: 100%;
}

.seat {
  display: block;
  background-color: #2d4d86;
  color: white;
  margin: 0.15%;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 1.7rem !important;
}
</style>
```

---EDIT---

Here is the App component, which uses the Hall component:

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <Hall style="z-index:999"/>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import Hall from "./components/Hall.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",

  components: {
    Hall,
    NavBar,

  },
};
</script>
```

```css
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Heebo:wght@300&display=swap');

html {
  overflow: hidden !important;
  background: #121212;
}

#app {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Heebo';
}
</style>
```

---END OF EDIT---

The problem I'm facing is this:
The intended use of the component is mobile. Whenever I switch to mobile view, I want to be able to scroll so that I could see all the seats instead of scaling them down.
But when I try to scroll to the left, some elements are pushed out of the screen and are unreachable.

[The component in normal mode (desktop view)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnqX1.png)

[I can scroll all the way to the right (mobile view)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgYJf.png)

[But not to the left (mobile view)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSwGp.png)

As you can see from the pictures, the last row of seats is the most obvious, as I cannot see past seat number 12.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The provided snippets do not produce the same output as your image. Is there some other css you haven't included? [codepen](https://codepen.io/RuggMatt/pen/RwxOMvV)

Comment: I haven't included the App component which uses this component

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't scroll to top of flex item that is overflowing container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454533/cant-scroll-to-top-of-flex-item-that-is-overflowing-container)