Center cards vertically in Ionic Grid (v7)
I have 2 cards that I want to center vertically.
On large screens, cards should be side by side on the same row. Row should be centered.
On small screens, cards should be on under the other.
I tried to use ion-justify-content-center as specified in documentation, but without success.
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button>Home</ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content color="primary" class="ion-padding">
 <ion-grid>
    <ion-row class="ion-justify-content-center ion-align-items-center">

      <ion-col size="12" size-sm="12" size-lg="12">
        <div class="ion-text-center">
          CENTERED TITLE
        </div>
      </ion-col>

      <ion-col size="12" size-sm="12" size-lg="6">
         <ion-card [button]="true" class="ion-padding">
              ...
         </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="12" size-sm="12" size-lg="6">
         <ion-card [button]="true" class="ion-padding">
              ...
         </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
   </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
</ion-content>

I should see something like this on large screen
===========================



       centered title

 *******            *******
 *******            *******
 *******            *******
 


============================

and like this on small screen
===================


  centered title

     *******
     *******
     *******

     *******
     *******
     *******
 

===================

Instead what I have, it's this below:
===========================
       centered title

 *******            *******
 *******            *******
 *******            *******
 





============================


The answers below are acceptable but theres a simpler way. Add those classes: ion-justify-content-center ion-align-items-center" to the ion-col not row, and it will work.

tried, it doesn't work.

Wrap your ion-grid in display: flex.
For example:
html:
<div class="flex-container">
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center ion-justify-content-center">
      <ion-col size="12" size-sm="12" size-lg="12">
        <div class="ion-text-center">
          CENTERED TITLE
        </div>
      </ion-col>

      <ion-col size="12" size-sm="12" size-lg="6">
        <ion-card [button]="true" class="ion-padding">
          ...
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="12" size-sm="12" size-lg="6">
        <ion-card [button]="true" class="ion-padding">
          ...
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</div>

css:
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}


tried. doesn't work. <ionic-content>  is 100% full height, but ionic automatically adds a div _ngContent height as just as the content, so not fully 100%. <ion-grid>will be child of this div, and not direct child of <ionic-content>

here is working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic7-label-test-tqtffg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

thank you. anyway, in that example if I have many elements stacked vertically, the first one will be not visible, because out of the view on top. The result is like first element would have a negative margin-top ...

you can add overflow: scroll on .flex-container..

the container is already scrollable, but the top element is still not visibile. It's traceable to this problem, that I am reading now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454533/cant-scroll-to-top-of-flex-item-that-is-overflowing-container

using your solution, and adding margin:auto to flex children, seems fixing the problem

Using @Najam solution, with a little extra modification, seems solve the problem (also of the vertical top scroll)
    <style>
      .centered-fullpage 
      {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        overflow: scroll;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .centered-fullpage > :first-child
      {
        margin:auto
      }
    </style>
    
    
    <ion-content class="ion-padding"> 
    <div class="centered-fullpage">
    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row class="ion-justify-content-center ion-align-items-center">
    
          <ion-col size="12" size-sm="12" size-lg="12">
            <div class="ion-text-center">
              CENTERED TITLE
            </div>
          </ion-col>
    
          <ion-col size="12" size-sm="12" size-lg="6">
             <ion-card [button]="true" class="ion-padding">
                  ...
             </ion-card>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col size="12" size-sm="12" size-lg="6">
             <ion-card [button]="true" class="ion-padding">
                  ...
             </ion-card>
          </ion-col>
       </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
    </div>
    </ion-content>

